# I need to select the Max id from a table returning all the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I hope to get some help and also I can explain myself clear enough about what I need to do.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT        
    id.ItemId, id.DocId AS LastVersion, 
    MONTH(d.docUploadDt) as MontUploaded, 
    YEAR(d.docUploadDt) as YearUploaded
FROM
    dbo.ItemDocument id 
INNER JOIN    
    dbo.Documents d on id.docId = d.docId
GROUP BY 
    ItemId, id.DocId, d.docUploadDt
```

This will return data like this (this is an example for one particular itemId):

```
ItemId  LastVersion MontUploaded    YearUploaded
1728903   1544371        2               2016
1728903   1544372        2               2016
1728903   1544373        3               2016
1728903   1544374        4               2016
1728903   1544375        4               2016
1728903   1544376        4               2016
```

And my purpose it is to retrieve the last Version of a document uploaded each month. I would like to get the following result

```
ItemId  LastVersion MontUploaded    YearUploaded
1728903   1544372        2               2016
1728903   1544373        3               2016
1728903   1544376        4               2016
```

I cannot figured out how to use MAX statement. Could anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Sergio

Comment: Sorry, it is for microsoft sql-server (I thought everybody uses Microsoft products  ;-) - just kidding )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `group by` month and year of uploaddate,itemid and select the `max` docid.

```
SELECT id.ItemId, MAX(id.DocId) AS LastVersion,
MONTH(d.docUploadDt) as MontUploaded, YEAR(d.docUploadDt) as YearUploaded
FROM dbo.ItemDocument id 
INNER JOIN dbo.Documents d on id.docId = d.docId
GROUP BY id.ItemId,YEAR(d.docUploadDt),MONTH(d.docUploadDt)
```

Comment: Fantastic!!! It is incredible how fast you have answered the question "CORRECTLY" in a matter of minutes.
Thank you very much for your help